# Github Action `dotnet build` works with `.editorconfig` but local one doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, github-actions, command-line-interface

GitHub Action `dotnet build` raised 4 error with `.editorconfig`, while local on Window 10, Monjara Linux, Ubuntu Linux installed manually or with package manage raised only one warning.
[GitHub Actions log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZmqA.png)
[Window 10 Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kHGY.png)

What is the difference between GitHub Action `dotnet` and freshly installed one?
How to make local `dotnet` behave as same from GitHub Actions?

P.S. Same project, same commit, same `.editorconfig` in `BotsCore\.editorconfig` not in solution root. Default `csproj` settings.

Reinstall `dotnet`, reinstall Linux, switch to Window.
Checked command in GitHub Action Job and nothing special at all.

Comment: You can run `dotnet --info` on each host to confirm versions and the installed SDKs and Frameworks. The `.editorconfig` is read by the static code analyzers that have been enabled in the project. If some of the analyzers are not available or are not running that could be the cause of the different results.